# Can I run code in different languages in "containers" and access each variable?

Tags: java, sockets, types

I know the question sounds dumb, but I couldn't frame it properly.
So, here's what I am expecting.

```
 #This is some programming language.
java_file = new Java()#creates a temp java named java_file which will be interpreted when this program runs. 
py_file = new Python()#creates a temp py file 
java_file{
/*The usual class declaration*/
x=6
}
x=java_file.get(x)#this variable is of the hypothetical language.
py_file{
print(MAIN.x)#MAIN.x refers to the previous defined value.
}
```

I am thinking of a programming language that supports all the language by running each in a seperate container,
So is there any way to do that? Preferably using Java.
This looks like sockets, but I want to take full control of each container, like being able to halt and resume and read internal states.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea: you could run local servers in each container to connect to, and in you're Java program which controls them you can create processes wrapped by a Language class which can send control packets to the servers using Sockets. This can also be used to access variables. See the concept below:

```
public abstract class Language {
    public Object getVariable(String variableName) {
        sendPacketToServer("get_variable " + variableName);
        return readResponse();
    }
}
```

Note: this leaves your options quite flexible and allows for remote control of programs too. However, if you wish you could send and receive data using process input and output streams.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:

- It is possible in theory assuming that you can specify clear semantics for this hybrid language.
- In practice, I know of no (implemented) hybrid language that operates like this.  Not even remotely.

---

The first (BIG) problem would be specifying a language that allowed you to embed other languages within it AND reference elements defined in the embedded languages.  The syntax and semantics needs to take account of the existing syntax and semantics of all of the languages that you are embedding.  Complicated, I imagine.

The second (BIG) problem would be implementing it.

- Do you try use existing implementations for the embedded languages?  How does the framework language control the embedded executions?  How does it stop the executions at the appropriate points and extract / inject values?
- Do you build new implementations (e.g. interpreters) that *run* in the "virtual machine" of the framework language?  Would the performance be acceptable?

---

It is an interesting idea ... but would the end result be worth it?  Are there convincing use-cases?  Do you have a way to resource a few man-years of effort (from people who know how to design and implement languages) to see if it will work?

Comment: I had been learning Java but only to the basics. I heard C is a great tool for this, but Java works too. I wonder if I can pull something much more similar to JVM, like a container. If that's even possible. As for how would I handle that "containers" I am thinking the new language will control the containers much like a parent and is able to interact with it. If possible can you guide/refer me the resources I need to learn. I still am in my HS and have a lot of time to try around and think over it.

Comment: Like I said.  This is a multi-year project for someone who is skilled in implementing programming languages.  That doesn't sound like you.  So, my advice for you would be to START by doing a 4 year computer science / software engineering degree, and making sure that you pick a University that has a strong courses in Compiler Design.

Comment: (Maybe you could do this as a final year project.  But if I was your advisor, I'd advise you that it was far too ambitious.)

Comment: As for resources to help you do this, I can't think of any.  This idea is so "out there" that it is unlikely that they even exist.   You are like an explorer in visit a new continent for the first time.  "Maps?  What maps?  You are drawing them!".  Of course there are all of the standard texts on compiler writing, but they don't deal with the unique problems of hybrid / nested / embedded languages.